# Adding Logins in SQL server 2008 via SMO. How do you properly create User Mappings?

Tags: .net, security, sql-server-2008, smo

I am automating login creations on a SQL Server 2008 database using SMO in VB.NET.  I have created the login, created the user in the database, given the user roles, and set the login name of the user to the login I created at the server level.

What I haven't been able to do is get the User Mapping right. But maybe I am misunderstanding something.  I am not a SQL Security guru by any means.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim TargetServerName As String = "MyServer"
    Dim TargetDBName As String = "PermissionTestDB"
    Dim strGroupName As String = "TestGroup"
    Dim TargetServer As New Server(TargetServerName)
    Dim TargetDataBase As Database = TargetServer.Databases(TargetDBName)

    ' First we will create a SQL Server Login
    Dim newLogin As New Login(TargetServer, String.Format("DOMAIN\{0}", strGroupName))
    newLogin.LoginType = LoginType.WindowsGroup
    newLogin.Create()

    'Next we will create a Database User login
    Dim dbLogin As New User(TargetDataBase, newLogin.Name)
    TargetDataBase.Users.Add(dbLogin)
    dbLogin.Login = newLogin.Name
    newLogin.DefaultDatabase = TargetDBName

    'Assign the Database Login some roles
    Dim DataReaderServerRole As DatabaseRole = TargetDataBase.Roles("db_datareader")
    Dim DataWriterServerRole As DatabaseRole = TargetDataBase.Roles("db_datawriter")
    DataReaderServerRole.AddMember(dbLogin.Name)
    DataWriterServerRole.AddMember(dbLogin.Name)

    'And Add a permission under the dbo schema
    Dim dboPermission As New ObjectPermissionSet(ObjectPermission.Alter)
    TargetDataBase.Schemas("dbo").Grant(dboPermission, newLogin.Name)

    'Map the Database User to the Server login
    Dim dbMapping As New DatabaseMapping(newLogin.Name, TargetDBName, dbLogin.Name)
End Sub
```

The last line creates a mapping, and in another sub I called the EnumDatabaseMappings method and the mapping is there, however when I go into Management Studio and go to SERVER>Security>Logins>"Domain\TestGroup">User Mappings page, the line in the list for PermissionTestDB is not checked.  In the grid below, I can see that the login and associated user have the db_datareader and db_datawriter roles enabled, but it is all grayed out.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  DatabaseMapping class doesn't have very extensive documentation, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sp_revokedbaccess 'username'
sp_adduser 'username'
sp_addrolemember 'role', 'username'
```

Comment: This is not working out for me.  When executing sp_adduser I continually return 'is not a valid login or you do not have permission.' despite the login having been created at the server level, and having permissions.  I can create the user in Management Studio without problem, same with the above VB.NET SMO procedure.

Comment: Did you USE targetdatabase first?

Comment: I did not, but after doing so, it returned the same thing.

Comment: Hmmm. I've only ever ran this when logged in as sa. You could try that.

Comment: Microsoft has the following to say on the sp_adduser page: "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.... Use CREATE USER instead." So I am going to go that route.  Thank you for the idea though.  Sometimes one gets so narrowly focused that they lose sight of more simplistic (and time proven) ways of doing things.

Comment: My codebase has to back-support as far as SQL 2000. I guess yours doesn't.